# Prove that $E[(X - m)^2] = E(X^2) - m^2$

Tags: probability, expectation

I can't figure out why the statement below is true. I am also confused why the first statement uses square brackets but the second statement uses round brackets.
Please advise.

From https://revisionmaths.com/advanced-level-maths-revision/statistics/expectation-and-variance :

The variance of a random variable tells us something about the spread of the possible values of the variable. For a discrete random variable X, the variance of X is written as Var(X).

$Var(X) = E[(X - m)^2]$            where m is the expected value E(X)

This can also be written as:

$Var(X) = E(X^2) - m^2$

Comment: Just google this!

Comment: See the '[Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition)' section on the Wikipedia page I have linked, starting from *"The expression for the variance can be expanded:"*

Comment: @Mathemagical got here by googling this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $m=\mathbb E[X]$,
then $$\mathbb E[(X-m)^2]=\mathbb E[X^2]-2\underbrace{\mathbb E[X]}_{=m}m+m^2=\mathbb E[X^2]-2m^2+m^2=\mathbb E[X^2]-m^2.$$

Comment: thanks, I was not aware of the identity $m=\mathbb E[X]$

Comment: @nn4l: You must have been aware, because you wrote it in your question!